# Nest for large values of n

Tags: equation-solving

I am working on a problem to find the [Feigenbaum constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FeigenbaumConstant.html). In this problem, I have to get $f^{2^n}(1/2)$ with $f(x) = kx(1-x)$. I use `Nest` to get $f^{2^n}(1/2)$, but it takes *Mathematica* forever to run with $n>5$; my goal is to get to $n=14$.

Does anybody know any function or trick to get $f^{2^n}(1/2)$ with a large value of $n$?

Comment: Ha! another stupid decision from SO 10K users http://stackoverflow.com/q/16261682/353410

Comment: Could you post your `Nest[]`code, please?

Comment: You do know that iterating the logistic equation eventually results in a periodic sequence, no? Find the period, and then you can extrapolate on what the $2^n$-th iterate ought to be.

Comment: you probably want to try starting value `0.5` instead of `1/2` (assuming you are interested in numeric result anyway). This speeds things up remarkably

Comment: @J.M.  Could you enlighten me? `f[x_] := k x (1 - x); k = 3; ListLinePlot@NestList[f, .5, 300]`

Comment: @belisarius Try k=2.9 or 3.1 or 3.4. You happen to be choosing a value of k right at a bifurcation, where the convergence to the fixed point is absurdly slow. But, of course, the iteration need not always converge to a periodic orbit; that's the point behind chaos.

Comment: @MarkMcClure JM told the OP to find the period. Is that possible in the general case? (that's why I asked for enlightenment :) )

Comment: @Mark, Ah, right. Past 3.8 is the chaotic region, if memory serves...

Comment: @J.M. 3.8 - ish.

Comment: @bel, usually, for finding the Feigenbaum constant, you're only dealing with the periodic region. But there are better approaches than this if you're computing the constant, IIRC.

Comment: @belisarius No, I don't think you can analytically find the attractive orbit in terms of k in a simple way.  What I think J.M. is suggesting is extrapolate from when the bifurcations occur. In fact, the existence of the Feigenbaum constant is really an assertion that such an extrapolation works.

Comment: I want to get the value of k that satisfy: f_k^{2n}(1/2)=1/2. So I use this: f[x_] = k x (1 - x); FindRoot[Nest[f, 1/2, 2^n] == 1/2, {k, kg}] with kg is an initial value of k. I found out that this run for so long when k>5 because of the Nest function.

Comment: @thewanderer I assume that you mean when n>5, but note that for n=5, your polynomial has degree 2^2^5. and it's simply not feasible to solve this using simple techniques.  You should look into some of the papers of Keith Briggs to learn his extrapolation techniques: http://keithbriggs.info/

Comment: @thewanderer as Mark suggested one of the best papers on this topic is by Keith Briggs named "A precise calculation of the Feigenbaum constants Mathematics of Computation". You will find it [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1991-57-195/S0025-5718-1991-1079009-6/S0025-5718-1991-1079009-6.pdf)

Comment: @PlatoManiac,@Mark McClure thank you for your precious help.
By the way, I found out that Mathematica evaluate the value of Nest[f,x,n] very fast if k is a number (not a parameter). So I try to find the solution by bisection method. It is much quicker than using FindRoot.

Comment: @thewanderer, when you say "the value of k" that satisfies `Nest[f, 1/2, 2^n] == 1/2`, is the intention to find *all* such values of k?

Comment: @SimonWoods I believe he's interested in a specific sequence of such k, the ratios of consecutive differences of which converges to Feigenbaum's constant.

Answer (score 6):

This is from an old notebook of mine. Not claiming it's the best nor even optimal. Surprisingly, it's well commented. I wrote it in a step-by-step fashion for demonstrational purposes for some class.

---

$$\text{$\delta $=}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \delta _n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }
   \frac{r_{n+1}-r_n}{r_{n+2}-r_{n+1}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac{\mu _{n+1}-\mu _n}{\mu _{n+2}-\mu _{n+1}}$$

where $r=4\mu$.

### Initial conditions

Calculating $\mu_0$, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$; defining `F` and `delta[n]` for higher `n`.

```
f[x_] := mu x (1 - x)
```

> `(* Numerically, find the values μ_n at which the 2^n
>   cycle is superstable, for the first few values of n. *)(* Superstable
>   orbits contain 1/2. *)`
>
> `(* We choose an initial value for x_0 to find bifurcation
>   points; we chose x_0=1/2, because why not *)`

```
eq0 = f[1/2] == 1/2;
mu0 = mu /. N[Solve[eq0, mu]][[1]]
```

> 2.

```
m = {};
AppendTo[m, mu0]
```

> {2.}

```
eq1 = f[f[1/2]] == 1/2;
mu /. N[Solve[eq1, mu]]
```

> {2., -1.23607, 3.23607}
>
> `(* There are three roots here. We can use FindRoot to find a
>   numerical solution; if we start near the expected solution, perhaps
>   we'll get it. *)`

```
max = First[Select[mu /. N[Solve[eq1, mu]], # > m[[1]] &]]
```

> 3.23607

```
FindRoot[f[f[1/2]] == 1/2, {mu, max}];
mu1 = mu /. %
```

> 3.23607

```
AppendTo[m, mu1]
```

> {2., 3.23607}
>
> `(* To get the later bifurcation points μ[n], we need a function
>   which iterates f many times. In Mathematica, the standard method
>   (Nest) actually expands the composition out algebraically before
>   plugging in: iterating f 2^12 times involves generating an expression
>   of order 2^12-1 long in mu. We use old-fashioned iteration to speed
>   things up. Unfortunately, Mathematica does things algebraically unless
>   we insist otherwise. We insist that x and mu be real numbers before
>   iterating! *)`

```
eq2 = f[f[f[f[1/2]]]] == 1/2;
mu2 =
 First[
  Select[
   Sort[
    Cases[
     mu /. N[Solve[eq2, mu]], _Real
     ]
    ], # > m[[2]] &
   ]
  ]
```

> 3.49856

```
AppendTo[m, mu2]
```

> {2., 3.23607, 3.49856}

```
F[x_Real, mu_Real, NTimes_] := Block[{y = x}, Do[y = mu y (1 - y), {NTimes}]; y]
```

Example:

```
mu /. FindRoot[F[0.5, mu, 2^2] == 0.5, {mu, Last[m]}]
```

> 3.49856

or within an interval:

```
mu /. FindRoot[F[1/2, mu, 2^2] == 1/2, {mu, 3.45, mu1, 3.55}]
```

> 3.49856
>
> `(* As n increases, there are more and more roots to
>   (f^(12))[1/2]=1/2. To find the right one, we have to be careful. What
>   we can do is use the fact that the roots are spaced in an approximate
>   geometric progression: μ[n]~μ[n-1]+(μ[n-1]-μ[n-2])/δ *)`

```
delta[n_] := (m[[n]] - m[[n - 1]])/(m[[n + 1]] - m[[n]])

delta[2]
```

> 4.70894

### Further recurrences

```
c[n_] := m[[n]] + (m[[n]] - m[[n - 1]])/delta[n - 1]

mu[n_] := mu[n] = mu /. FindRoot[F[1/2, mu, 2^n] == 1/2, {mu, c[n]}]

Do[AppendTo[m, mu[n]], {n, 3, 11}]

m
m // Length
```

> {2., 3.23607, 3.49856, 3.55464, 3.56667, 3.56924, 3.5698, 3.56991,
>   3.56994, 3.56994, 3.56995, 3.56995}
>
> 12

No need to go to bigger `n` as there's no additional convergence.

### Onset of chaos is at r=...

```
Last[m]
```

> 3.56995

### Feigenbaum constant

```
Table[delta[n], {n, 2, Length[m] - 1}]
```

> {4.70894, 4.68077, 4.66296, 4.6684, 4.66895, 4.66916, 4.66919,
>   4.6692, 4.6692, 4.6692, 4.6692, 4.66919, 4.66919}

```
Last[%]
```

> 4.66919

### Plots

```
plot1 = ListPlot[Table[{n, m[[n]]}, {n, 1, Length[m]}], Frame -> True,
   PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Medium]}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 2}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"n", 
    Rotate["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(n\)]\)", 270 Degree]}]
plot2 = ListPlot[Table[{n, delta[n]}, {n, 2, Length[m] - 1}], 
  Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Medium]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  FrameLabel -> {"n", 
    Rotate["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Delta]\), \(n\)]\)", 270 Degree]}]
```

[image]

[image]

> `(* δ is converging nicely to the universal value. *)`